# FetchMode only works with primary key Column

Tags: hibernate, fetch

I have changes the code but the issue is still there

```
    CandidateResumeInfo candidateResumeInfo = new CandidateResumeInfo();
    ArrayList<CandidateResumeInfo> allCandidateResumeInfo= new ArrayList<CandidateResumeInfo>();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String city1 ="Anniston";

    Criteria  crit = session.createCriteria(CandidateResumeInfo.class);
    crit.createAlias("candidate", "candidateinfo");

    //crit.setFetchMode("candidateinfo", FetchMode.JOIN);
    crit.add( Restrictions.eq("candidateinfo.city", city1));
    List list = crit.list();
```

here is the entity class ..
public class CandidateResumeInfo implements Serializable{
...

```
      @OneToMany     
      CandidateInfo candidate;

      ....
      }
      public class CandidateInfo implements Serializable{
      .......

     @Column(name="city")
     private String city;
      .......
      }
```

Here are top top few lines of stack trace
This is some RPC.class  ( it comes at this line which says                      Throwable cause = e.getCause();and at the right variables side(in debug mode) there's written java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     ,                           but there is nothing java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  in the stack trace

```
   public final class RPC {
    .......
   public static String invokeAndEncodeResponse(Object target,
  Method serviceMethod, Object[] args,
  SerializationPolicy serializationPolicy, int flags)
  throws SerializationException {
if (serviceMethod == null) {
  throw new NullPointerException("serviceMethod");
}

if (serializationPolicy == null) {
  throw new NullPointerException("serializationPolicy");
}

String responsePayload;
try {
  Object result = serviceMethod.invoke(target, args);

  responsePayload = encodeResponseForSuccess(serviceMethod, result,
      serializationPolicy, flags);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  SecurityException securityException = new SecurityException(
      formatIllegalAccessErrorMessage(target, serviceMethod));
  securityException.initCause(e);
  throw securityException;
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  SecurityException securityException = new SecurityException(
      formatIllegalArgumentErrorMessage(target, serviceMethod, args));
  securityException.initCause(e);
  throw securityException;
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  // Try to encode the caught exception
  //
  **Throwable cause = e.getCause();**   // THIS IS THE LINE WHERE IT BRINGS ME ..

  responsePayload = encodeResponseForFailure(serviceMethod, cause,
      serializationPolicy, flags);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
crit.createAlias("Class2", "c2").add(Restrictions.eq("c2.zip", 123)
```

should do it...

If you simply use 'zip' hibernate will look for a property zip in class Class1; it has nothing to do with the property being PK or not.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the code as u said , still not resolved ,kindly review the code above (i have pasted the actual code)and let me know if i'm doing some thing wrong             thanks

Comment: `crit.createAlias("CandidateInfo" ...);` if your property is called candidate this should be `crit.createAlias("candidate", ...`

Comment: changed it ,also edited above ,Issue is still there ,  Any Suggestion .do i need to do something at some other place as well to make a JOIN. thanks

Comment: Which issue do you face exactly; do you have an exception?

Comment: at the above line  List list = crit.list();
its goes exception    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  but if i use candidateinfo.id instead of candidateinfo.city  it works fine (as id is the primarykey) ,but i want to link with city not id ,want to set some criteria on city in csndidateinfo class.   thanks

Comment: Hibernate will automatically join on the id, there is now way around this but this is ok. You need to join on id and then filter on city. Does your query work without the createAlias and restriction? Append the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: yes , it does work without createAlias and restriction . i've tried to put full track here but it says text limit exceeded

Comment: @junaidp, see http://benpryor.com/blog/2006/08/15/java-dynamic-proxies-and-invocationtargetexception/ if it helps.
For stack trace, you can try putting top few lines.

Comment: thanks , the site didnt help , i have attached the stack trace above ,i dont think it will be useful .  if you want i can email you the complete

Comment: This is not the stacktrace but just a part of the logging; we need the part that starts with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and the caused by's.

Comment: This is code, still not a stacktrace. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110991/java-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-with-digester-parser) is a stacktrace